# Wrapper and container do different layout

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I need to make a responsive email with the foundation framework, where the color is going full width (like the wrapper example below) and the text are centered (like the container example). I am stuck because if I use the wrapper class the text is flying to the left, and I cannot center the text. If I am using the container, I cannot get the color to go full width, but the text is centered. There is around 10 rows, and each row has a different color.

[image: The layout]

**With the wrapper:**

[Wrapper Example](http://roulettesuite.com/ny.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-emails.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <table align="center" class="wrapper">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="row">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="background-color: red;">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>This is a column. Columns contain your content.</th>
                      <th class="expander"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**With the container**
[Container Example](http://roulettesuite.com/ny-container.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-emails.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <table align="center" class="container">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="row">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="background-color: red;">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>This is a column. Columns contain your content.</th>
                      <th class="expander"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The promise that you will lose your job unless a volunteer rushes to help you is emotional blackmail of the worst kind, and is entirely unacceptable here. I have covered this kind of begging [in this Meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326576/472495).

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the `background-color` style to the body instead of having it on the `th` and give the `table.container` a transparent background.  Would that work?

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-emails/2.2.1/foundation-emails.min.css)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-emails.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="background-color: red;">
      <table align="center" class="container" style="background-color: transparent;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="row">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th>This is a column. Columns contain your content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</th>
                          <th class="expander"></th>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: green;">
      <table align="center" class="container" style="background-color: transparent;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="row">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th>This is a column. Columns contain your content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</th>
                          <th class="expander"></th>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## EDIT:

Here's a working version with the responsiveness based on what I could piece together from the framework.

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-emails/2.2.1/foundation-emails.min.css)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-emails.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="body">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
          <table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center" style="background-color:red"><tbody><tr><td class="wrapper-inner">
            <table align="center" class="container" style="background-color:transparent"><tbody><tr><td>

              <!-- single column row -->
              <table class="row collapse"><tbody><tr>
                <th>This is a column. Columns contain your content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</th>
                </tr></tbody></table>
                
            </td></tr></tbody></table>
          </td></tr></tbody></table>
          <table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center" style="background-color:green"><tbody><tr><td class="wrapper-inner">
            <table align="center" class="container" style="background-color:transparent"><tbody><tr><td>

              <!-- two column row -->
              <table class="row collapse"><tbody><tr>
                <th class="small-6 large-6 columns first"><table><tbody><tr><th>
                  <p>BASIC</p>
                  </th></tr></tbody></table></th>
                <th class="small-6 large-6 columns last"><table><tbody><tr><th>
                  <p>BASIC</p>
                  </th></tr></tbody></table></th>
                </tr></tbody></table>

            </td></tr></tbody></table>
          </td></tr></tbody></table>
        </td>
        </tr></tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. The problem is that each row has a different color like my picture. Therefore I cannot set it on the body.

Comment: @McDuck4 Theoretically, if all you're doing is changing the color, a simple div wrapper with the color wrapping each container should work then.  It really depends on how the end result is supposed to look.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Omg yes that is working. But is it okay to have a div tag in an email?

Comment: argh shoot I can see that the text is not responsive

Comment: @McDuck4 div is a supported tag in every email client, so yes.  Mostly the thing to watch out for is what styles are supported.  https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ can help with that part.

Comment: @McDuck4 I'm not familiar with this framework, so I'm not sure how the responsiveness works.  Maybe we can get a complete example and see how it responds?

Comment: There is some in the documentation here, but not a lot. It is mostly how the structure is. Shoot I just got so happy. `http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/grid.html` , but mostly with the wrapper is here `https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/wrapper.html`

Comment: How do you under stand the section: "Full (fluid) width header or footer" in `https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/wrapper.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134030/discussion-between-joseph-marikle-and-mcduck4).